# combine or add values in Action Script 2.0?

Tags: timer, actionscript-2, addition, number-formatting

I'm new with AS and trying to add values using either arrays of functions to combine values but they do keep showing NaN.

```
function combine(a, b, c):Number{
  return a + b + c;  
}
var total = combine(myTimer1, myTimer2, myTimer3);  
totalTimers.text = total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the part of your code that generates `myTimer1`, `myTimer2` and `myTimer3` I can't be sure exactly why this is happening, but it seems that those variables are either not of the type `Number` or have values of `null` or `undefined`.

I would recommend starting by tracing out the values of `myTimer1`, `myTimer2` and `myTimer3` (or inspecting them in the debugger) to see which of these is causing the problem.